# Deleting files using vbs without hard coding variables

Tags: vbscript

How can I modify following script in order to avoid hard coding location, date-stamp and extension into it and specify those details as input variables in command prompt like for example "cscript del.vbs d:\temp 16/08/2013 jpg".

```
    OPTION EXPLICIT
    DIM strExtensionsToDelete,strFolder
    DIM objFSO, MaxAge, IncludeSubFolders

    ' ************************************************************
    ' Setup
    ' ************************************************************

    ' Folder to delete files
    strFolder = "d:\test\"

    ' Delete files from sub-folders?
    includeSubfolders = TRUE
    ' A comma separated list of file extensions
    ' Files with extensions provided in the list below will be deleted
    strExtensionsToDelete = "jpg"
    ' Max File Age (in Days).  Files older than this will be deleted.
    maxAge = 1

    ' ************************************************************

    SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DeleteFiles strFolder,strExtensionsToDelete, maxAge, includeSubFolders

    wscript.echo "Finished"

    SUB DeleteFiles(BYVAL strDirectory,BYVAL strExtensionsToDelete,BYVAL maxAge,includeSubFolders)
        DIM objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
        DIM strExt

        SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
        FOR EACH objFile in objFolder.Files
            FOR EACH strExt in SPLIT(UCASE(strExtensionsToDelete),",")
                IF RIGHT(UCASE(objFile.Path),LEN(strExt)+1) = "." & strExt THEN
                    IF objFile.DateLastModified < (NOW - MaxAge) THEN
                        wscript.echo "Deleting:" & objFile.Path & " | " & objFile.DateLastModified 
                        objFile.Delete
                        EXIT FOR
                    END IF
                END IF
            NEXT
        NEXT    
        IF includeSubFolders = TRUE THEN ' Recursive delete
            FOR EACH objSubFolder in objFolder.SubFolders
                DeleteFiles objSubFolder.Path,strExtensionsToDelete,maxAge, includeSubFolders
            NEXT
        END IF
END SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cscript command looks ok.
Then, add this to your vbscript to capture the arguments

```
location = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
date-stamp = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
extension = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
```

Note, they are all strings, so you will need to parse your date value to an actual date.

Comment: Would you be able to advice how the script was supposed to look like after this modification?

Comment: @McSenstrum  "date-stamp" is not a vaild variable name; accessing the .Arguments collection without index check is dangerous.